# Werkzeug(Flask) response with redirect not working

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I'm building a simple `Flask` application and I want to return redirect response. Also, I want to maintain total control over headers.

This is what I've got so far:

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.wrappers import Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/toexample')
def to_example():

    headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0',
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    }

    return Response('www.example.com', status_code=302, headers=headers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'status_code'
```

Ok, it looks like `status_code` doesn't exist on `__init__()`, but what is the right way of doing this?

What I ultimately want is a link that a user would click but again, I want to maintain control over headers(**Connection, Cookies, Referer, etc.**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add `Location` to headers. Also, `status_code` is wrong, it should've been `status=302`.

Working example:

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.wrappers import Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/toexample')
def to_example():

    headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0',
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            'Location': 'http://www.example.com'
    }

    return Response('http://www.example.com', status=302, headers=headers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think of that! Take a look at my example. Let me know what you think. I was skeptical about my solution actually. Interesting...

Answer (score 4):

This does the trick for me:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/toexample')
def to_example():
    response = redirect("http://www.example.com", code=302)
    headers = dict(response.headers)
    headers.update({'X-Custom-Header1': 'value1', 'X-Custom-Header2': 'value2'})
    response.headers = headers
    return response
```

This works for me on `Flask`  `v0.10.1`. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you want to make use of here. Firstly, for the re-direct you want to make use of `redirect` in your `to_example` call:

```
@app.route('/toexample')
def to_example():
    return redirect("http://www.example.com", code=302)
```

Now, for the control over custom headers and cookies, what you can do is make use of [after_request](http://@app.route('/toexample')%20def%20to_example():%20%20%20%20%20return%20redirect(%22http://www.example.com%22,%20code=302)) which will allow you set certain custom specifics after you a make a request to your response object:

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Custom-Header', 'Custom Header')
    response.headers.add('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    response.set_cookie('some-cookie', value='some-cookie-value')
    return response
```

Putting that all together, your example now looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/toexample')
def to_example():
    return redirect("http://www.example.com", code=302)


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Custom-Header', 'Custom Header')
    response.headers.add('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    response.set_cookie('some-cookie', value='some-cookie-value')
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is a curl call. Note the header.

```
▶ curl -v http://127.0.0.1:5000/toexample
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET /toexample HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 302 FOUND
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 251
< Location: http://www.example.com
< Custom-Header: Custom Header
< Content-Type: application/json
< Set-Cookie: some-cookie=some-cookie-value; Path=/
< Server: Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/3.5.0
< Date: Sun, 01 Nov 2015 23:11:30 GMT
<
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<h1>Redirecting...</h1>
* Closing connection 0
<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: <a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a>.  If not click the link.%
```

Comment: I've tried that but it's just printing `www.example.com` and not redirecting at all. What is `response` expected to be, a string?

Comment: @intelis Let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks for your response, though i feel like my way is cleaner :)

Comment: to be honest, i didn't think of that on my own :) It's how it's done in `Flask` source where `redirect` is defined ;)